# Using a dictionary i would like to have this string sequence ACCTAGCCCTA as {'AC': 1, 'CC': 3, 'CT': 2, 'TA': 2, 'AG': 1, 'GC': 1}

Tags: python

Using a dictionary I would like to have the string sequence "ACCTAGCCCTA" as `{'AC': 1, 'CC': 3, 'CT': 2, 'TA': 2, 'AG': 1, 'GC': 1}`
but  my code  gives me  `{'AC': 1, 'CC': 2, 'CT': 2, 'TA': 2, 'AG': 1, 'GC': 1}`, only CC 2.

```
p = input(str("entrez une chaine de caractere"))
dic = {p[i:i+2] : p.count(p[i:i+2] ) for i in range(len(p)-1)}
print(dic)
```

Why is that and what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

For an efficient solution, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a generator expression:

```
s = 'ACCTAGCCCTA'

from collections import Counter

out = dict(Counter(s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)))
```

Output:

```
{'AC': 1, 'CC': 3, 'CT': 2, 'TA': 2, 'AG': 1, 'GC': 1}
```

##### variant without import

```
out = {}
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    out[s[i:i+2]] = out.get(s[i:i+2], 0)+1
```

Comment: yes right it seems efficient  thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with `zip` + `Counter`,

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: s = 'ACCTAGCCCTA'

In [3]: dict(Counter(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(s,s[1:]))))
Out[3]: {'AC': 1, 'CC': 3, 'CT': 2, 'TA': 2, 'AG': 1, 'GC': 1}
```

Comment: I prefer direct slicing as it can easily be generalized to chunks of greater size (3, 4 letters) ;)

Comment: @mozway I agree with you. I was almost posting the approach you took, :). So, just curious about some other approach. Just found one, and posted it. Simple, :)

Comment: To be fair, my first reflex was also `zip` ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for this, but you have to [install it](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):

```
In [41]: from more_itertools import sliding_window

In [42]: s = "ACCTAGCCCTA"

In [43]: from collections import Counter

In [44]: Counter(sliding_window(s,2))
Out[44]: 
Counter({('A', 'C'): 1,
         ('C', 'C'): 3,
         ('C', 'T'): 2,
         ('T', 'A'): 2,
         ('A', 'G'): 1,
         ('G', 'C'): 1})

In [45]: Counter(sliding_window(s,4))
Out[45]: 
Counter({('A', 'C', 'C', 'T'): 1,
         ('C', 'C', 'T', 'A'): 2,
         ('C', 'T', 'A', 'G'): 1,
         ('T', 'A', 'G', 'C'): 1,
         ('A', 'G', 'C', 'C'): 1,
         ('G', 'C', 'C', 'C'): 1,
         ('C', 'C', 'C', 'T'): 1})
```